# Select Data not have a key in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, inner-join, not-exists

I have two tables
1- Dates Table

```
------------
|    Date   |
------------
| 1/11/2020 |
-----------
| 2/11/2020 |
------------
```

2- Revenues

```
    ------------------------------------
    |  revDate  |  Name     |  Revenue  |
    ------------------------------------
    | 1/11/2020 |  Joe      |   500 $   |
    ------------------------------------
    | 2/11/2020 |   Dani    |   400 $   |
    ------------------------------------
    | 4/11/2020 |   Sami    |   300 $   |
    ------------------------------------
```

I need a query to return name of user not submit a revenue in a date table
the query should return :

```
    ------------------------------------
    |  Date     |  UserNotSubmit        |
    ------------------------------------
    | 1/11/2020 |  Dani                 |
    ------------------------------------
    | 1/11/2020 |  Sami                 |
    ------------------------------------
    | 2/11/2020 |  Joe                  |
    ------------------------------------
    | 2/11/2020 |  Sami                 |
    ------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate all combinations of dates and names with a `cross join` then fiter out those that exist:

```
select d.date, n.name
from dates
cross join (select distinct name from revenues) n
where not exists (select 1 from revenues r where r.revdate = d.date and r.name = n.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively apply `CROSS JOIN` and then `LEFT JOIN` such as

```
SELECT rr.revDate AS Date, rr.Name AS UserNotSubmit
  FROM
  ( SELECT r1.revDate, r2.Name, r1.Name AS Name2
      FROM Revenues r1
     CROSS JOIN Revenues r2) rr
  LEFT JOIN Revenues r3
         ON r3.revDate != rr.revDate
        AND r3.Name = rr.Name 
 WHERE r3.revDate IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY rr.revDate
```

**Update :** Indeed the above query brings all the non-matched records without need of the `Date` table, but if you want to filter out due to the matching values of `Date` column of `Date` table, then apply a simple (`INNER`) `JOIN` such as

```
WITH Rev AS
(
SELECT rr.revDate AS Date, rr.Name AS UserNotSubmit
  FROM
  ( SELECT r1.revDate, r2.Name, r1.Name AS Name2
      FROM Revenues r1
     CROSS JOIN Revenues r2) rr
  LEFT JOIN Revenues r3
         ON r3.revDate != rr.revDate
        AND r3.Name = rr.Name 
  WHERE r3.revDate IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT r.*
  FROM Rev r
  JOIN Date d
    ON d.Date = r.Date
  ORDER BY r.Date
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b68ee4efd4cc8bb3fb7624ee908dc560)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use anti-join as follows:

```
SELECT D.DATE, R.NAME FROM DATES D
JOIN REVENUE R ON D.DATE <> R.REVDATE
```

Comment: This would, for eaxmple, bring date `4/11/2020`.

Comment: How? I have used the D.DATE